# Some imperfections about `Rationalize`, `Chop` and other functions related to `N`

Tags: plotting, numerics

I find, in version 11 on Windows 7,64 bit, in the following example that, `Rationalize` and `Plot` together give unnecessary warnings (ps: this example can be find in documentation center: [`ref/Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html))

```
Plot[Log[Abs[Pi - Rationalize[Pi, Exp[-n]]]], {n, 0, 20}]
```

> Rationalize::tolnn: Tolerance specification E^-n must be a non-negative number.
>
> Rationalize::tolnn: Tolerance specification 2.71828^(-1. n) must be a
>   non-negative number.
>
> Rationalize::tolnn: Tolerance specification 2.71828^(-1. n) must be a
>   non-negative number.
>
> General::stop: Further output of Rationalize::tolnn will be suppressed during this calculation.

For `Chop` and other functions related to `N`, similar things occur.

Answer (score 4):

This behaviour is not surprising, in fact it is quite expected.  `Exp[-n]` is not a number.  It is a symbolic expression.  It only becomes a number if we substitute a number for `n`.  Read more here:

- [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037)

Why would this be in the documentation then?  `Plot` is such a commonly used function (also by complete beginners) that they made it try to guess your intention and automatically decide whether the evaluate the input symbolically or not.

I noticed that several cases where plotting functions didn't evaluate symbolically in v11.0.0 started evaluating in v11.0.1, e.g. [the StreamPlot here](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/neural-networks/learn-a-parameterization-of-a-manifold.html?product=language).  Maybe this is one of those cases.

Still, the answer is: you should control the evaluation manually as the software won't be able to *guess* what you meant with perfect accuracy.

```
f[n_?NumericQ] := Log[Abs[Pi - Rationalize[Pi, Exp[-n]]]]

Plot[f[n], {n, 0, 20}]
```